# Collapse of states after measurement in different basis

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-states, quantum-measurements

This question came when I was reading the paragraph after theorem 1 of arxiv paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.07744 about a measurement on a set of states called the PBR states
\begin{equation}
|00\rangle, |0+\rangle, |+0\rangle, |++\rangle
\end{equation}
where $|0\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is the eigenstate of $+1$ eigenvalue for Pauli $Z$ operator and  $|+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is the eigenstate of $+1$ eigenvalue for Pauli $X$ operator.
From what I understand, the paper claims that the measurement of these states in the basis of eigenstates of $Y\otimes Y$ (tensor prod of Pauli $Y$ operators) will map $|00\rangle$ and $|++\rangle$ to post-measurement states that are orthogonal to each other if the outcomes for both $Y$ measurements are equal (either both being $+1$ or both being $-1$). (The same goes for post measurement states of $|0+\rangle$ and $|+0\rangle$ if the outcomes for both $Y$ measurement are different.) However my calculation based on my understanding has not been able to show this.

From what I know, Born rule suggests that the post-measurement state of state $|\psi\rangle$ given measurement outcome $j$ from projective measurement $\{P_j = |j\rangle\langle j|\}_j$ is
\begin{equation}
\frac{P_j|\psi\rangle}{\sqrt{|\langle j|\psi\rangle|^2}}.
\end{equation}
So, writing
\begin{equation}
|0\rangle = \frac{|y_+\rangle+|y_-\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \quad\text{and}\quad |+\rangle = \frac{(1-i)|y_+\rangle+(1+i)|y_-\rangle}{2}
\end{equation}
for $|y_+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1\\i\end{bmatrix}, |y_-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1\\-i\end{bmatrix}$ and considering projector $|y_+\rangle\langle y_+|$ corresponding to outcome $+1$ we have post-measurement states for $|00\rangle$ and $|++\rangle$
\begin{equation}
\frac{|y_+ y_+\rangle}{2\sqrt{1/4}} \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{|y_+ y_+\rangle(1+i)(1-i)}{4\sqrt{1/4}}
\end{equation}
which clearly are not orthogonal.

Am I missing something here? or did the paper meant something else?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. If you take an arbitrary input state $|\psi\rangle$ and project onto the same eigenvector of $Y\otimes Y$ (or any other operator), of course you get always the same state, which is the eigenvector itself (up to scalar factors)

Comment: Yes, that what I was wondering. My other question that you commented on is directly related to this.